# Environment variables from .env and/or docker-compose not replaced in Dockerfile CMD

Tags: c#, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to pass a couple of environment variables from an .env file in the root of the project to the Dockerfile's CMD. I've read through the numerous other similar questions here on SO but nothing has made this work. What am I doing wrong?

.env (in root of project)

```
TOKEN=AToken
DECK=ADeck
```

docker-compose.yml (in root of project)

```
version: "3"
services:
  discord-initiative-savageworlds:
    build:
      context: .
    environment:
        - TOKEN=${TOKEN}
        - DECK=${DECK}
```

And the Dockerfile (in root of project):

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
ARG TOKEN
ARG DECK
...Run Installers and Stuff...
COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish
RUN cd DiscordInitiative/bin/Debug/net5.0/publish
RUN echo "${TOKEN}"
CMD ./DiscordInitiative --token="${TOKEN}" --deck="${DECK}"
```

Running `docker-compose up` builds the project successfully, but the CMD shows that the environment variables are not being replaced:

```
Step 12/13 : RUN echo "${TOKEN}"
 ---> Running in 7096ef978516

Removing intermediate container 7096ef978516
 ---> 6985b62bb75e
Step 13/13 : CMD ./DiscordInitiative --token="${TOKEN}" --deck="${DECK}"
```

The project & branch this is in is on GitHub [here](https://github.com/bensulli/discord-initiative-savageworlds/tree/feature/docker-deploy).

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: If you actually run `docker-compose up`, does it get the right command?  That looks like it's just echoing the Dockerfile command; everything in the Dockerfile gets processed before Compose `environment:` variables are considered, but when it runs, first the environment gets set up and then that command gets executed (with an implicit `sh -c` wrapper which will expand the variables).  That is: I think this should work and you're being misled by the build diagnostics.

Comment: This may be it (in combination with the below answer) - retesting now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .env file and the `environment` directive in your docker-compose file are Docker Compose concepts applying at runtime, not applying to image build. Your configuration would inject those environment variables to the built, running container, but it won't inform the build environment.

*(Edit: Upon reflection, this may be what you actually **want**.)*

You could fully leverage the `ARG` instruction in your Dockerfile by changing your docker-compose to say:

```
version: "3"
services:
  discord-initiative-savageworlds:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - TOKEN=${TOKEN}
        - DECK=${DECK}
```

This will effectively set your 'environment' at build time, and will enable your Dockerfile to function as pasted above.

### Edit:

I suspected there might be things in the redacted portion of the Dockerfile that could throw wrenches. The TL;DR from our comment thread is that your Dockerfile would need to change, too:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
...Run Installers and Stuff...
COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish
RUN cd DiscordInitiative/bin/Debug/net5.0/publish
ARG TOKEN
ARG DECK
RUN echo "${TOKEN}"
CMD ./DiscordInitiative --token="${TOKEN}" --deck="${DECK}"
```

Moving those `ARG` instructions as near to the bottom as possible sets them from your docker-compose.yml **after** a bunch of other `RUN` instructions, and similar things that have the potential to blow away the intermediate container state.

### Edit 2:

In reality, though, what you're asking for is variables that are available in the container at runtime (when `CMD` is executing). So, your question would lead me to believe that you don't need the `ARG`s at all, and that your container would function as expected.

Also, if you eliminate the `ARG`s you can get rid of the `RUN echo ...`, as that would never return anything at that point in the build process.

Injecting `ARG`s is totally **not** what you want to do with sensitive values, as the arguments then become a part of your image layers, and subject to snooping. The pattern of injecting sensitive values to the environment at runtime is much preferred (though I wouldn't say most preferred).

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same result with this change to the docker-compose.

```Step 12/13 : RUN echo "${TOKEN}"
 ---> Running in e9f01a895c98
AToken
Removing intermediate container e9f01a895c98
 ---> 699f8b5b3425
Step 13/13 : CMD ./DiscordInitiative --token="${TOKEN}" --deck="${DECK}"```

Comment: Ah, hold on, may have found it.

Comment: It works when I move the `ARG`s in the Dockerfile to right above the echo. Some of the `RUN`s in your sequence are blowing away the intermediate layers where the `ARG`s were originally set. I pulled your branch and have a commit with the working changes, but I don't have permission to commit ;)

Comment: Aha, that's helpful thank you!

Comment: I'll edit the solution for posterity. Glad you're on track!

Comment: So this works, but only if I include environment _and_ args in my docker-compose, which seems redundant and probably points to my misusing them elsewhere.

eg:
```version: "3"
services:
  discord-initiative-savageworlds:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - TOKEN=${TOKEN}
        - DECK=${DECK}
    environment:
        - TOKEN=${TOKEN}
        - DECK=${DECK}
```

When I match your docker-compose (without environment) above and the full Dockerfile (https://github.com/bensulli/discord-initiative-savageworlds/blob/main/Dockerfile) I still get a failed token result.

Comment: The environment values in the Docker Compose file set the environment in the running container. So, your ARGs will help at build time, but your CMD is the first thing that executes when the container starts.

Comment: If your ARGs are sensitive values, you should not include them in the build and should just use the environment to inject them at runtime.